# Flutter two listview.builder on same page with dynamic height

Tags: list, listview, dynamic, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using flutter. I have two dynamic lists of item available and items unavailable.
I want to show both lists in a way that it shows complete available item list then complete unavailable item list and flutter will decide the length dynamically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a small example should show red Container for available items and blue items for unavailable items.

```
List<int> unavailable;
List<int> available;

Expanded(
    child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
  SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final item = available[index];
        if (index > available.length) return null;
        return Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0); // you can add your available item here
      },
      childCount: available.length,
    ),
  ),
  SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final item = unavailable[index];
        if (index > unavailable.length) return null;
        return Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 150.0); // you can add your unavailable item here
      },
      childCount: unavailable.length,
    ),
  )
]));
```